Conversion problem from TIFF to DTED using GDAL
I have downloaded a 30 m resolution DSM. I am trying to convert it from .tif to .dt2 (DTED) using the gdal translate command. However, I get the following warnings, which I do not interpret correctly:

Warning 1: The source does not appear to be a properly formatted cell.
Warning 1: The corner coordinates of the source are not properly aligned on plain latitude/longitude boundaries. 
Warning 1: The horizontal source size is not conformant with the one expected by DTED Level 1 at this latitude (3600 pixels found instead of 1800).

It produces an extension of the file but without any elevation values. I have tried reprojecting but it still doesn't work. Also for the levels, I apply the dt2, but still get the message about level 1.
I also tried the process in ArcMap using the Raster to DTED tool. Once I ran it, it immediately said executed but didn't produce any results.
Any suggestions?
